# What's another word for an 'outlet' in a creative sense?

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a specific word I'm looking for. It's a means of expression or a focus for your energy or skills.

"I need an '*insert-word-here*' for my creativity"

Comment: If you had not already suggested it, I would have said *outlet*.

Comment: Target or canvas (metaphorically).

Comment: If you are trying to be concise, you just tell us how you would express this in your own wordy way. It's impossible to guess what you are asking.

Comment: What’s wrong with *outlet*?

Answer (score 1):

I need an 'avenue' for my creativity.

I need a 'release' for my creativity.

I need to 'unleash' my creativity.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the word channel or avenue would be good alternatives